# Flexbox - How to split row 50/50 between two elements and wrap if width falls below min-width?

Tags: css, angular, flexbox, angular-material

I have a simple div which contains two mat-cards. Here are the CSS attributes of the div and of the cards inside the div:

```
.cards {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

mat-card {
  margin: 10px;
  width: 45%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

Here is an example HTML template to reproduce the problem:

```
<div class="cards">
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title> Card 1 </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      Name: Test 1 <br />
      Type: Type 1 <br />
      Property 1: 1 <br />
      Property 2: 2 <br />
      Property 3: 3 <br />
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
  <mat-card>
    <mat-card-header>
      <mat-card-title> Card 2 </mat-card-title>
    </mat-card-header>
    <mat-card-content>
      Name: Test 2 <br />
      Type: Type 2 <br />
      Property 1: 1 <br />
      Property 2: 2 <br />
      Property 3: 3 <br />
    </mat-card-content>
  </mat-card>
</div>
```

I want each of the cards to fill 50% of the row. If the min-width of the cards is too large to fit both cards into the row, the div content should wrap so the cards are now below each other. After the wrap, each card should fill 100% of the available width.

With my current CSS layout, the content wraps way too early and I also can't seem to just set the width of the cards to 50% each because this causes it to wrap immediately. Here is a stackblitz which illustrates the problem:
[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-lw9mx4?file=src/app/app.component.css)

How can I get the desired behavior?

Comment: Could you please supply the editor url of the stackblitz via the `Share` button

Comment: @ChrisHamilton Yes! I just edited my question. I thought I already provided the editor url but apparently I didn't.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: I've answered the question, but please paste your html and css into the question so it doesn't rely on the external link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change `width: 45%` to `flex-grow: 1`, the flex items will try to take up the whole row. `flex-basis` controls how large they are in relation to eachother, by default they will attempt to stay the same size. Currently they wrap at `332px` because of the `16px` of padding.

```css
mat-card {
  margin: 10px;
  min-width: 300px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! `flex-grow: 1` did the trick. I guess I was too focused on the standard width properties so I forgot about the flexbox-specific ones.